# Facebook MessageDialog doesn't open Android

Tags: android, facebook, api

I'm trying to make it possible for people to send a link to one of their friends, I'm using the facebook API. The problem is that the send dialog doesn't show up, when I try to make a share dialog however it opens without any problem.

This is my code (it is set in a listadapter because in the list are different items that have the send_button (which is a normal button)):

```
        CallbackManager callbackManager = CallbackManager.Factory.create();

        final MessageDialog messageDialog = new MessageDialog((Activity)context);
        messageDialog.registerCallback(callbackManager, new FacebookCallback<Sharer.Result>() {
            @Override
            public void onSuccess(Sharer.Result result) {
                Log.e("test", "send success");
            }

            @Override
            public void onCancel() {
                Log.e("test", "send cancel");
            }

            @Override
            public void onError(FacebookException e) {
                Log.e("test", "send error");
            }
        });
        send_button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Log.d("test","clicked");
                ShareLinkContent linkContent = new ShareLinkContent.Builder()
                        .setContentTitle("Test")
                        .setContentDescription("heytest")
                .build();

                messageDialog.show(linkContent);
            }
        });
```

The context is what is given through from the mainactivity. I don't get why it isn't working I've also overwritten the onActivityResult() method in the mainactivity.

I would appreciate some help, thanks.

Comment: what's printed to logcat? I suspect that your hash is incorrect

Comment: What should I be looking for? There seems to be nothing unusal in logcat

Comment: clear the filter for your application, clear logs just before tap and then capture the logs and see if there is anything suspicios